# Header при поднятии наверх оставляет полосу бэкграунда, как исправить?

Tags: html, css, битрикс, битрикс24

Если спуститься вниз и затем вернуться на самый верх, то есть момент перехода между меню и заглавной картинкой.

Что можно добавить в css, чтобы переход был без полосы выделенной на скриншоте ниже?

ссылка на сайт: https://sunnycyprus.by/

[image: ыы]

Answer (score 1):

Hot Fix. Но нужно разбираться почему JS отрабатывает позже чем нужно

```
header.landing-block.landing-block-menu.u-header.u-header--floating.u-header--floating-relative + div {
  display: none;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Эффект явно из-за белого блока с логотипом и контактами (`.landing-block-node-top-block`).
Он пропадает когда начинаешь скроллить вниз, а появляется после того, как доскролливаешь в самый вверх.

Его появление является плавным (сверху вниз, или увеличение его высоты).
Уверен, что по разметке расстояние от верха до `#main` уже учитывает наличие `.landing-block-node-top-block` и `.navbar` - из-за этого и появляется проблема описанная в вопросе.

Думаю решить это можно добавлением "плавного" появления как у `.landing-block-node-top-block` блоку `#main`